# Как перевести строковые данные во множество без разбиения на символы?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Даны два столбца фрейма данных, один числовой, второй в виде строки записанных через пробел чисел.

Необходимо сформировать третий столбец булевых значений, в котором 1 - число `col1` входит в множество числе из `col2`, а 0 - не входит.

Пытаюсь через `np.where()`, но метод `.apply(str)` дробит двузначные числа в строке на множество из двух элементов.

Как создавать множества из строки без разбиения?

Ниже пример для воспроизведения кейса:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[10,'20 10 3'],[20,'1 45 60'],[30,'46 32 9']],columns=['col1','col2'])
df.col1 = df.col1.apply(str) 
print(df.col1.apply(set))
np.where((df.col1.apply(set)) & (df.col2.str.split(' ').apply(set)),1,0)
```

Результат:

```
0    {0, 1}
1    {2, 0}
2    {0, 3}

array([0, 0, 0])
```

А должно быть:

```
array([1, 0, 0])
```

Comment: можете привести пример результата, который вы хотите получить?

Comment: По идее должно `df.col1.isin(df.col2.str.split(' '))` работать, но что-то у меня не работает %)

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
df["col3"] = (df["col2"]
              .str.split("[\s\,]", expand=True)
              .isin(df["col1"])
              .any(axis=1)
              .astype("int8"))
```

результат:

```
In [330]: df
Out[330]: 
  col1     col2  col3
0   10  20 10 3     1
1   20  1 45 60     0
2   30  46 32 9     0
```

Comment: Благодарю! Как всегда, живу Вашими советами!